# Изменение переменной при нажатие кнопки

Tags: php, html

Подскажите, облазил кучу форумов, но что-то лижи не едут...

Есть переменная в PHP

```
$SALE = false;
```

Как сделать чтобы при нажатии одной кнопки она меняла значение на true, если другая кнопка то false. И вообще это реально?

Comment: причем тут java?

Comment: это нереально))

Comment: троллинг дело хорошее...

Comment: @ТарасЛейтар куда без него))) просто добавьте ваш код и что было сделано и что вызвало трудности, так вам быстрее ответят

Comment: К сожалению нет ничего, уточняю просто, может есть литература или ссылка в которой будет пример

Comment: @ТарасЛейтар уточните тогда для чего это переменная, что планируете сделать, тогда дам ответ уже адекватный

Comment: Это нереально. `PHP` - скриптовой язык. Он один раз выполнился, страничку выдал, и выгрузился. Там нет такого: мол он ждет пока вы кнопочку нажмете. НО вы имеете инструменты, чтобы вызывать какой-то сценарий после нажатии на кнопку, это смотреть в сторону `html form` и `ajax` - выбирайте.

Comment: Вообще то сделать можно

Comment: Наверное вам нужен JavaScript а если и всё-таки PHP то с исполнением AJAX тогда. А вообще вам в помощь html form, $_get, if, session

Answer (score 0):

> *Как сделать чтобы при нажатии одной кнопки она меняла значение на true, если другая кнопка то false*

```
<?php

session_start();

$sale = isset($_SESSION['sale']) ? $_SESSION['sale'] : null;

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $_SESSION['sale'] = key($_POST);
    die(header('Location: ?'));
}

?>

<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="true" value="true">
    <input type="submit" name="false" value="false">
</form>

<?=$sale?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать так, грубо конечно, но работает:

```
<form action="index.php" method="get">
    <button type="submit" name="type" value="1">TRUE</button>
    <button type="submit" name="type" value="0">FALSE</button>
</form>
<?php
    $sale = null;
    if (isset($_GET['type']) and $_GET['type'] == 1) {
        $sale = true;
    } elseif (isset($_GET['type']) and $_GET['type'] == 0) {
        $sale = false;
    }
    var_dump($sale);
?>
```

Comment: Делаю, первый файл: same.php

       <form action="api_for_mobile.php" method="get">
       <button type="submit" name="type" value="1">TRUE</button>
       <button type="submit" name="type" value="0">FALSE</button>
       </form>

Второй файл: api_for_mobile.php

       $SALE = null;
       if (isset($_GET['type']) and $_GET['type'] == 1) {
       $SALE = true;
       } elseif (isset($_GET['type']) and $_GET['type'] == 0) {
       $SALE = false;
       }
       var_dump($SALE);

Comment: И ничего не происходить, объясню, файл api_for_mobile, переменная $SALE отвечает выводить на экран приложения цены или нет, если false то нет

Comment: А почему файл same.php, а action="api_for_mobile.php"? И имя $SALE в верхнем регистре, не очень хорошая практика. Я привел простой пример который создав файл index.php и поместив туда код будет работать. Если вы хотите, что то более конкретное, то объясните задачу более детально

Comment: Есть файл api_for_mobile.php который в приложение передает переменную $SALE = false; (означает что цены для акции скрыты) , когда мы редактируем ее на true, то цены в приложении меняются, к чему все это, мне не тяжело зайти и поменять с false на true, но хочется сделать так, чтобы человек заходил на отдельную страницу и нажав кнопку менял с false на true, могу прикрепить код для понимания